# Posts get displayed in 2 different tabs on a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a problem with one of my Facebook pages. It is a page where I regularly publish posts via WordPess (Jetpack).

Automatically publishing posts via WordPress works. But when I visit my page, I see the following sections in the middle content (or are they called panels?) are:

- Post form
- Statistics
- Posts
- Photos
- Posts

Yes, you are reading correctly, the "Posts" section appears twice. But they don't have the same content. The first "Posts" section (Posts #1) shows not more than two posts. If I create another post through the post form, it will be added to Posts #1 and remove the last post in that section, so that no more than two posts are being displayed. There is no difference if I attach an image or not.

The second "Posts" section (Posts #2) below "Photos" shows all the other posts that were published on this page. What I would like to do is having all posts in the same section.

I have tried rearranging the tabs through the "Manage Tabs" option, but this seems to only affect the order of the links in the left bar. To compare: This is my current tab order

[image: current tab order]

and this navigation links on the left site of the page. It has absolutely no effect on the sections in the main content.

[image: navigation links on the left side of the page]

I have also tried turning on and off the option "Use default tabs" on the "Edit page" screen.

My goal is to have all posts in the same section. If possible, I would also like to change the order of the sections displayed on my page.

**Note:** To not reveal my identity, I cannot provide a link to this Facebook page. I can, however, post redacted screenshots.